Bake color ramp
i have a model in blender that i want to export, but when i do it it doesn't have textures. The fix for this is to bake my color ramps to an image, but when i do it, the image that is created is just a flat color, and not an image with some different colors.



You could do a render, then keep the camera view, do a U (Unwrap) > Project from View in Edit mode, and project the render onto the surface, except you'll still have to paint the other parts (back of the object)

Can you explain it a bit more im kinda new to blender!
